# Do waves clash or collide, or both?

Tags: terminology, sounds

Are hard waves *crashing* on rocks? Do waves *collide* in the ocean?

Comment: Using "crashing waves" is way more common in my experience, but you could call them colliding waves for sure.

Comment: It's a Physics question.

Comment: I don't see either description fitting the situation, *clashing* or *colliding* have meanings slightly different from the way waves "crash."

Comment: @Kris Hmm I thought they said "crashing"? Yea, clash not at all. But I've seen crashing waves used in many situations. Not so much collide; though it works.

Comment: They also *pass through* each other. You have a relatively free hand in choosing the words that best describe the experience you're trying to relay.

Comment: What examples of "waves collided" etc have you found on the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Crash as a transitive verb means "to break violently," MW. As an intransitive verb it means "to break or go to pieces with." Crash is an apt description of  waves meeting rocks, and is commonly used. Collide means "to come together with solid impact," MW. Waves coming from two or more directions (wind conditions or a point break, etc.) do collide, that is meet each other with a solid impact.

Answer (score -2):

Technically waves **pass through each other** in the ocean, its called "superimposition". They dont "collide", which also carries a sense that they impact and stop, or are broken, etc. There's no collision.  But that may not be much help in writing nontechnically.

Comment: Useful comment. Not an answer.

Comment: "They don't collide" is an answer. I can't comment on the subjective description of whether waves hitting rocks is crashing.

Comment: Please go through the FAQ section and earn a badge!

Comment: -1. In linear wave theory, it is superposition, not superimposition; although the two are used interchangeably in some other disciplines. And ocean waves are often not very well modeled with linear theory. They can and do collide. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EleV3tgF20